# How can i make my signup form using api and ajax to direct users to their email for verification?

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, crud

if i have a simple CRUD API and jQuery-ajax app running to add (post) users (sign up :
 name-email ). 
How can i make my app while adding new users to direct them to their email in order to verify the signup via a clickable link and that link will confirm the new data (user)?

Any reply, links or hints will be highly appreciated.
Thank you very much.
Refo.﻿

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely not possible in exactly the way you define it.  A mailto link will bring up the compose window in the user's default email program.

One option would be to have an icon or link to hotmail, gmail, yahoomail and a couple of other public email services that are most commonly used.  You can detect which one the user is using from the email address. Each one of these services has a specific URL to access the inbox, which you can provide in the link or clickable icon.  Of course, many email domains will not be detectable.

For in-house corporate email addresses, an advanced option would be to check the MX DNS records for the domain of the email address entered, and use that to determine whether it is Office 365 or Google Mail for apps and then construct the URL.

Keep in mind that no single solution will work for all cases.

Comment: Thank you for ur answer, but u made it sound like impossible :(